# Best way to compare three columns in sql Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I need to do some comparison through 3 columns containing string dates 'yyyy-mm-dd', in Hive SQL. Please take in consideration that the table has more than 2 million records.

Consider three columns (col1; col2; col3) from table T1, I must guarantee that:

1. col1 = col2, and both, or at least one is different from col3.

My best regards,

Comment: I'd try `col1 = col2 and col1 <> col3 and col2 <> col3`, `col1 = col2 and col1 <> col3` and `col1 = col2 and col2 <> col3`

Comment: Thanks @jarlh, but I'm looking for a more efficient way to solve this.

Comment: Like the accepted answer...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically you have an issue.

col1 = col2

Therefore if col1 != col3 then col2 != col3;

There for it's really enough to use:

```
select * from T1 where col1 = col2 and col1 != col3;
```

It is appropriate to do this map side so using a `where` criteria is likely good enough.

If you wanted to say 2 out of the 3 need to match you could use `group by` with `having` to reduce comparisons.